# How to test singleton(a class only new once) on laravel

Tags: laravel, testing

This is `Residence` Facade:

```php
class Residence extends Facade
{
    protected static function getFacadeAccessor()
    {
        return 'residence.manager';
    }
}
```

Here is the provider:

```php
class ResidenceServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider implements DeferrableProvider
{
    public $singletons = [
        'residence.manager' => ResidenceManager::class,
        'residence.japan' => ResidenceJapan::class,
        'residence.us' => ResidenceUS::class,
        'residence.eu' => ResidenceEU::class,
    ];

public function provides()
    {
        return [
            'residence.manager',
            'residence.japan',
            'residence.us',
            'residence.eu',
        ];
    }
```

The  ResidenceManager Class:

```php
class ResidenceManager 
{
    protected $app;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->app = app();
    }

    public function make($data)
    {
        $residenceService = match ($data['location']) {
            'japan' => $this->app['residence.japan'],
            'us' => $this->app['residence.us'],
            'eu' => $this->app['residence.eu'],
            default => false
        };

        if (!$residenceService ) {
            return false;
        }

        return $residenceService->make($data);
    }
}
```

> I try to test if `ResidenceJapan::class`, `ResidenceUS::class`, and `ResidenceEU::class` only new once.

I use spy, bu it give me

```
Mockery\Exception\InvalidCountException 

  Method make(<Any Arguments>) from Mockery_0_App_Services_Residence_ResidenceJapan should be called
 exactly 1 times but called 3 times.
```

```php
    /**
     * @dataProvider residenceSeedProvider
     */
    public function test_residence_class_only_new_once($data, $expected)
    {
        $residence= match ($data['location']) {
            'japan' =>
            [
                'bind' => 'residence.japan',
                'class' => ResidenceJapan::class
            ],
            'us' =>
            [
                'bind' => 'residence.us',
                'class' => ResidenceUS::class
            ],
            'eu' => [
                'bind' => 'residence.eu',
                'class' => ResidenceEU::class
            ],
            default => 'unknown',
        };

        $spy=$this->spy($residence['class']);

        $this->app->instance(
            $residence['bind'],
            $spy
        );
        $i = 3;
        while ($i > 0) {
            //$this->assertNotNull(Residence::make($data));
            Residence::make($data);// don't know why the Residence::make($data) return null
            $i--;
        }
        $spy->shouldHaveReceived('make')->once();
    }
```

So I use mock, but it give me

```
Error 

  Call to undefined method App\Services\Residence\ResidenceJapan::shouldHaveReceived()
```

```php
    /**
     * @dataProvider residenceSeedProvider
     */
    public function test_residence_class_only_new_once($data, $expected)
    {
        $residence= match ($data['location']) {
            'japan' =>
            [
                'bind' => 'residence.japan',
                'class' => ResidenceJapan::class
            ],
            'us' =>
            [
                'bind' => 'residence.us',
                'class' => ResidenceUS::class
            ],
            'eu' => [
                'bind' => 'residence.eu',
                'class' => ResidenceEU::class
            ],
            default => 'unknown',
        };

        $mock = Mockery::mock($residence['class'], function (MockInterface $mock) use ($expected) {
            $mock->shouldReceive('make')->once()->andReturn($expected);
        });

        $this->app->instance(
            $residence['bind'],
            $mock 
        );
        $i = 3;
        while ($i > 0) {
            $this->assertNotNull(Residence::make($data)); // the Residence::make($data) return what I am expected
            $i--;
        }
        $residence['class']::shouldHaveReceived('make')->once();
    }
```

How do I test if `ResidenceJapan::class`, `ResidenceUS::class`, and `ResidenceEU::class` only `new` once, no matter how many times the Facade `Residence::make($data)` calls?

Comment: First of all can you please try shouldReceive method name instead of shouldHaveReceived.

Comment: @RBC not working, and the laravel document use `shouldHaveReceived`, it only use `shouldReceive` to create a spy or a mock.

Comment: You don't need shouldReceive and shouldHaveReceived at the same time? wouldn't shouldReceive not be enough?. Your problem with shouldHaveReceived, is that you are calling it on the class implementation and not the mock. To be fairly honest, there is a lot of clever approaches in these code snippet, that make it quite hard and confusing to understand what is going on. Which could be an idea to actually change the approach.

Comment: @mrhn Thanks for you reply, can you share other approaches?